# How do I run a collection of similar methods in a python class?

Tags: python, oop

I am working with a large Python class with dozens of "business logic" methods and a few helper methods. There is some funny code at the end that is being used to run all "calc_metric_*" methods.

Something that looks a bit like:

```
class CalculateMetrics:
    ...

    def calc_metric_x1(self):
        ...

    def calc_metric_x2(self):
        ...

    def calc_metric_x3(self):
        ...

    def calc_metric_x4(self):
        ...
    
    ...

    def calc_metric_x50(self):
        ...

    def run_all(self):
       method_list = [m for m in dir(self) 
                      if callable(getattr(self, m)) 
                      and m.startswith('calc_metric_')]

       for m in method_list:
           # Call each method
           getattr(self, m)()
```

The use of `getattr` + referencing the method's name doesn't seem optimal to me. Is there a better way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: To be fair, the code works.

Comment: No, they each encode unique business logic, but are quite related. I found a way to use a decorator around the each method definition to "add them" to a register and/or add an attribute to the method object to make it more explicit what methods are helpers and which should be run by the `run_all()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a decorator function that collects them like this:

```py
def calc_metric(func):
    if func not in calc_metric.calc_metric_funcs:
        calc_metric.calc_metric_funcs.append(func)
    return func


calc_metric.calc_metric_funcs = []
```

Then you need to decorate all the desired functions with `@calc_metric`:

```py
    @calc_metric
    def calc_metric_x1(self):
        
        ...

    @calc_metric
    def calc_metric_x2(self):
        ...

    ...

    @calc_metric
    def calc_metric_x50(self):
        ...
```

And you `run_all()` function will be like this:

```py
    def run_all(self):
        for f in calc_metric.calc_metric_funcs:
            f(self)
```

Note that the `calc_metric` function must be declared outside of the `CalculateMetrics` class.

Comment: Yes, perfect. This seems to be the best way.